# PHP mysql insert bool value dynamically

Tags: php, mysql

i'm currently working on a project with PHP MySQL and I want to insert bool val dynamically.

for example when we add dynamic date we use like `$created = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['created']));` and using a regular string we use it like `$name = $_POST['name'];` so how can we set dynamic POST method for bool?. and is there another complicated value assignment like this one?

Comment: A bool will arrive in the POST data as some sort of string, depending on how your client side sends it. So you'll have to parse that and then assign true or false to a php variable based on the submitted value. Does that help? The precise issue is a bit unclear.

Comment: it really helps . but how can i use that in my `INSERT INTO...`, is there a way to convert the string value and assign it as a bool?

Comment: Yes there is, a simple ternary operator would do the trick. But that has not nothing to do with sql. With sql you just pass it in as a parameter, and it doesn't really matter what the type is

Comment: Let's say for example the POST variable contains either 1 or 0 you could write `$aBoolVar = ($_POST["boolValue"] == 1 ? true : false);`